# Find the largest non overlapping interval

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a task list `[[5, 9], [1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 6], [5, 7], [8, 9]]`. Each of the sub list has two time intervals. (Eg: [5, 9] in which 5 is starting time and 9 is ending time). I want to get a list which has the maximum of times which does not overlap with each other. For an example in this case: `[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 7],[8, 9]` is the best schedule.

I have written a python program which is supposed to find out the combinations of other intervals if start with one of the intervals. 
For an example if I start with [5,9] it must return all the possible combinations. Then I can input all the intervals one by one and choose the largest output.

But my code is not giving the expected output. Please help me to find out what's wrong with the code.

```
def findMax (tasks):
    maxCount = []
    maxTask = []
    for i in range (len (tasks)):
        if maxTask == []: maxTask.append (tasks [i])
        else:
            count = 0
            for j in range (len (maxTask)):
                if tasks [i] == maxTask [j]: continue
                else:
                    if (tasks [i][0] < maxTask [j][0] and tasks [i][1] <= maxTask [j][0]) or (tasks [i][0] >= maxTask [j][1] and tasks [i][1] > maxTask [j][0]): count += 1
                    if count == len (maxTask): maxTask.append (tasks [i])
        maxCount.append (len (maxTask))
        maxTask = []
    return max (maxCount)
```

Comment: it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: This sounds like a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) - which is np-hard, and only practical for very small data sets. There are multiple efficient approximate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it works for me:

```
def getCombi(tasks):
    first = getNext([0,0], tasks)
    combi = [first]
    while True:
        nextTask = getNext(combi[-1],tasks)
        if nextTask != ["EmptyTask"]:
            combi.append(nextTask)
        else: break
    return combi

def getNext(MainTask, tasks):
    i = MainTask[1]

    taskDiffrencesList = []
    for task in tasks:
        if task[0] > i:
            x = task[0]-i
        else: continue
        d = task[1]-task[0]
        taskDiffrencesList.append([[x,d],task])

    smallestDiffrence = [10000, ["EmptyTask"]]

    for entry in taskDiffrencesList:
        if entry[0][0]+entry[0][1] < smallestDiffrence[0]:
            smallestDiffrence[0] = entry[0][0]+entry[0][1]
            smallestDiffrence[1] = entry[1]
    return smallestDiffrence[1]

print(getCombi([[5,9],[1,2],[3,4],[0,6],[5,7],[8,9]]))
```

So there is a loop that looks for the best next task depending on the differences to the previous number, and between the numbers of the next task, for example if the previous task was task1 = [3,5] and an other is task2 = [7,10] the differences are 2 (between task1[1] and task2[0]) and 3 (between task2[0] and task2[1]). Then it takes the task with the lowest sum of the two differences. This will maybe not always give you the right list but almost.

Hope that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function that recursively traverses through all the remaining tasks that don't overlap with the existing list of viable tasks, and yields the viable tasks when there is no more task in the remaining tasks that doesn't overlap with any of the viable tasks:

```
def schedule(tasks, viable_tasks=None):
    if not viable_tasks:
        viable_tasks = []
        tasks = sorted(tasks)
    found_viable = False
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(tasks):
        for viable_start, viable_end in viable_tasks:
            if viable_start < start < viable_end or viable_start < end < viable_end or start < viable_start < end or start < viable_end < end:
                break
        else:
            found_viable = True
            yield from schedule(tasks[:i] + tasks[i + 1:], viable_tasks + [[start, end]])
    if not found_viable:
        yield viable_tasks
```

so that:

```
tasks = [[5, 9], [1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 6], [5, 7], [8, 9]]
max(schedule(tasks), key=len))
```

returns: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7], [8, 9]]`